# convert an array to an object with childs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array with `element id` and `element parent` fields as bellow:

```html
[
  { id: 1, parent: 0 },
  { id: 2, parent: 0 },
  { id: 3, parent: 0 },
  { id: 4, parent: 3 },
  { id: 5, parent: 3 },
  { id: 6, parent: 5 },
  { id: 7, parent: 6 },
]
```

I want to covert this array like this:

```html
[
  { id: 1, childs: null },
  { id: 2, childs: null },
  { id: 3, childs:
    [
      { id: 4, childs: null },
      { id: 5, childs: 
        [
          { id: 6, childs: 
            [
              { id: 7, childs: null }
            ] // 6 .childs
          }, // 6
        ] // 5.childs
      }, // 5
    ] // 3.childs
  }, // 3
]
```

In other words consider the first array as a list of comments, which I want to show theme using Angular's `ng-repeat` directive with nested ng-repeats to show the child comments.

So how can I convert the first array to the second one in a proper way and good performance?

Comment: Each element in the top array should be an object and not another array right? In other words, the `id` and `childs` properties should be wrapped in curly braces and not brackets.

Comment: yes each element is an object. I edit it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean approach would be using map/reduce.

```
var array = [
  { id: 1, parent: 0 },
  { id: 2, parent: 0 },
  { id: 3, parent: 0 },
  { id: 4, parent: 3 },
  { id: 5, parent: 3 },
  { id: 6, parent: 5 },
  { id: 7, parent: 6 },
];

array.map(function(el){
  el.children = array.filter(function(item){
    return item.parent === el.id
  });
  return el;
}).filter(function(item){
  return item.parent === 0;
})
```

Which results in:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "parent":0,
      "children":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "parent":0,
      "children":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "parent":0,
      "children":[
         {
            "id":4,
            "parent":3,
            "children":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "parent":3,
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":6,
                  "parent":5,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "id":7,
                        "parent":6,
                        "children":[

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Filtering the properties you need is up to you and this can be easily done by mapping those elements one more time :)

P.S.: this isn't the best solution in terms of asymptotical complexity, but it's short and elegant.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Its very elegant :)